# -(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated method didnot called in ios sdk 5 but called in ios sdk4

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios4, uiviewcontroller

I have got this issue that -(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated method is getting called when I run this view in 4.3 simulator but it's not called when I am running the app in 5.0 and more simulator.
Can you explain why?

Comment: are you using xib files for interface initialisation ?

Comment: Maybe something more about issue? What exactly you are doing? Some steps to reproduce such behavior?

Comment: Are you trying to achieve some kind of ViewController containment? One ViewController inside anotherViewController?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to replicate this but in my case its calling **viewWillDisappear:** in both cases
(simulator4.3 and 5.0)This is what I have done

1> created new projected 
2> added a UIbutton in viewWillAppear:
3> on btn clicked presenting new controller modally using **presentModalVIewController:(BOOL)animated**

every time it present new controller

it is calling **viewWillDiappear:(BOOL)animated** of parent controller